# How to use track bar with different data representation?

Tags: c#, hex, data-conversion, trackbar

The questions is how to get data from trackbar like hexa numbers. 
What I need is: get values from 1 to 64 on the ride side and on the other side(-1 to -64) will be data represending data from 81 to E4.
I set my trackbar on min -64 and max 64 and set default value to 0.
I my plan is use If condition some like this:

```
if (trackBar1.Value <= -1)
{
    PM = trackBar1.Value; //any magic code to convert my value
}
else
{
    PM = trackBar1.Value;
}
```

Is there any ways how to do it?

Comment: Sorry I cannot see the pattern of the data conversion, 81 to E4?? Write 64 switch-case statements :)

Comment: yes sound like good start point. I will use for now! 
thanks for supp! :D

Comment: Surely if the minus values should be from 0x81 to 0xE4, just do `PM = 0xE5 + trackBar1.Value`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The right way for me was:

```
PM = Convert.ToByte(trackBar1.Value);
```

Thanks for help to every one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a track bar whose values run from -64 through to +64.
Where the trackbar value is below 0, you want to return figures from 0x81 to 0xE4, and where the trackbar value is above 0, you wan to return figures from 1 to 64 as normal.

In this case, it's a simple case of performing a different calculation depending on whether the value is below 0 or above it:

```
if (trackBar1.Value <= -1)
{
    PM = 0xE5 + trackBar1.Value;
}
else
{
    PM = trackBar1.Value;
}
```

Where the value is below 0, this will add the negative value to 0xE5, which will give you the appropriate value in the range 0x81 to 0xE4.